# Bokeh slider.py example not sliding

Tags: python, windows, slider, bokeh

On Windows, I copied the code of [Bokeh 0.12.13 slider](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/gallery/slider.html) into a Jupyter notebook with Numpy+MKL 1.14.0 installed and bokeh 0.12.4 installed in WinPython-64bit-3.4.4.6Qt5.  The graph came up with the sliders, but the sliders didn't do anything.   This is either by doing an output_notebook show or doing file_html show into another browser. Both inside Jupyter in Chrome and as a standalone page in Explorer, the sliders didn't slide.   No error messages popped up.

I then tried installing the latest Bokeh 0.12.13.  This latest Bokeh has two problems:

- It says there is no Resize tool and complains about that
- When you do show(p) for a plot p, nothing happens in Jupyter

The web example linked above works fine, so I don't think it's a matter of Internet Options not letting me run Javascript code.

Any thoughts?

Comment: That code works fine for me if I change `output_file` to `output_notebook`, in IE, Chrome, and Safari. What version of the notebook? Recent Bokeh versions require notebook >= 5.0

Comment: What about the Resize tool?  Do you see that in Bokeh 0.12.13 or is it gone?  Also, I did do output_notebook() in my Jupyter notebook.  My Jupyter version is hard to tell.  I have Jupyter 1.0.0, Jupyter Client 4.4.0, Jupyter Console 5.0.0, and Jupyter Core 4.2.1.  Does that add up to Jupyter Notebook 5.0?  Also, why would the file_html version fail to work in the browser, away from Jupyter?

Comment: The actual notebook packages is now just called `notebook`, that is the package that has to be >= 5.0 The `ResizeTool` was deprecated and removed quite some time ago, it was not compatible with other features. I don't know why the `output_file` version would not work, I agree that is strange. Is there any browser JS console errors?